# Can't take value from series in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get value from the pandas series. Like in the arrays I'm trying to get 3. value with tempArray[3] but the code gives me where the value inside the tempArray is equal to 3.

```
whichPhoto = 2
testY.index[whichPhoto]-> this gives index of it
testY.get(whichPhoto) -> this gives the id where value == 2 i don't want this
testY[[whichPhoto]] -> this also gives the id where value == 2 i don't want this 
testY[[testY.index[whichPhoto]]] -> this gives correct ansver but in wrong format like (id,value)
```

I only need a value where id is n. like in this example value of 2. array index inside the testY.

I want the value tempArray[5] not the value where tempArray is equal to 5 the code interestingly gives me the second one.

As you can see in the photo I'm trying to get the green value (76) with the index of the photo (18 in this example).

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to say. Please read [ask] and [mre], and show us: what is a *complete* input to the program? What is the *exact, complete* result you expect (don't just describe it; write it out, with proper formatting)? What actually happens when you run the code, and how is that different? Make sure that we can copy and paste your code, without changing anything or adding more information, and see the problem ourselves.

Comment: Sorry in advance It's too late at night and I'm coding for a long time. I rewrite it hope it makes it clearer. If possible can you review the question again?

Comment: What does `testY` look like before the code runs? What is the "correct answer" that you want for that input? Why? What is `whichPhoto`, and what does it have to do with `getValue`? What do you mean about "id"s?

Comment: `testY` is not defined

Comment: Please show some code that we can run ourselves. Then describe in more detail what output you are getting and what the output should be instead.

Comment: Sorry about my lack of English. I'll add a photo in a very short time to make it clear.

Comment: Don't add a photo.  When you say "series", do you mean this is a pandas `Series` object?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get the index from the pandas series with id value.

Comment: @SefaKalkan, are you looking for `testY.iloc[18]`, i.e., the 19th entry in the pandas series `testY`?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler yes that's what I was looking for thank you sir could you make it an answer so I can close the question, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're looking for:

```
testY.iloc[18]
```

This retrieves the 19th entry in the series `testY`, as opposed to the value where the index is `18`.

Documentation on `iloc`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html